# Partition Theorem and Markov Chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains, integer-partitions

Suppose a Markov chain has $s$ states, $S = {1, 2, . . . , s}$, with PTM $P =$ ($p_{ij}$). That is, $p_{ij} = P[X_{n+1} = j | X_n = i]$. Use the Partition Theorem to verify that if $X_n ∼ ν$, then $X_{n+1} ∼ νP$. Here $ν = (ν_1, . . . , ν_s)$ is a probability distribution on $S$.

What is this question asking me to do?

Comment: It asks you to find the probability distribution of $X_{n + 1}$, given you know the probability distribution of $X_n$ is $\nu$.

Comment: You can do that using the law of total probability: $P[X_{n+1}=j]=\sum_i P[X_{n+1}=j \mid X_n=i] P[X_n=i]$.

Comment: The law of total probability essentially solves the problem then. I can show that the PTM is the conditional probability in the equation and the the multiplication of the vector $v$ and the PTM is the same as $X_{n+1}$. Is it that simple?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed that simple.